# FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase Error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

Tags: firebase, react-native

as you can see by the question, I am having trouble using Firebase in my app. I initialized the Firebase object and used the configuration from my Firebase account. Additionally, I have been able to authenticate users (I have a semi-functional login system going). So far, users can login to existing accounts and create new accounts. However, I am trying to store data with my user (during registration) by taking the uid from the user and using that in my Cloud Firestore. After they register, I am trying to store the other fields (firstName, lastName, school, etc.) into the Cloud Firestore under the uid.

```
this.props.firebase
   .auth()
   .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
   .then((auth) => {
      this.props.firebase
      .database()
      .ref("users/" + auth.user.uid)
      .set({data})...
```

It successfully creates the user but doesn't let me store the information in the Cloud Firestore and throws the error I displayed above. Can anyone help? Thank you!

**Note: this.props.firebase is the reference to the firebase object instantiated with firebase.initializeApp()**

Answer (score 4):

Hahahaha, I suppose that I needed to actually create a real-time database in order for it to work. I had set up the Cloud Firestore while using the Realtime Database methods. Sorry to all for your troubles.

Comment: thank you for saving me very much time lol